# Why does OAuth 2.0 specification recommends the use of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" Media Type?

Tags: oauth2

I have a situation where the requests can't be of application/x-www-form-urlencoded Media Type and so the question.

Answer (score 2):

Interoperability. The OAuth standardizes format and names to ensure different implementations can work together out of the box as much as possible.

Why do you have a situation where you can't use this format? All major programming languages have libraries that implements this format, many as part of standard libraries.